# Renamng and Deleting specific NA's in dataset in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I'm rather new to this and I could use some help.
I like to achieve 2 things in R. At the moment i have a dataset called "researchdata".

#### 1. I like to manipulate the data in one specific column.

Let's say I want to change the text "New York" to "NY" in the column/variable "City". (so not the whole dataset at once) I'm not sure the command is different but i also like to do that with a number, for example change "-1" to "NA".

#### 2. Deleting a specific value in a specific column

How do i delete the NA's or missing values or actually any kind of value or string for a specific column. Lets say I want to delete both the values "NA" and "-1" for the column/variable city.

I tried some commands but I couldn't get them work, they weren't what i was looking for. I hope you guys can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: As for question 1; 
Well for example I came up with this;
mydata$city[mydata$city == -1] <- NA
So i managed to turn the -1 value into a NA.
But i can't turn the 0 value into for example "hello" 
mydata$city[mydata$city == 0] <- HELLO
Error: object 'HELLO' not found
As for question 2;
I then tried to delete NA only for a specific colum as shown below
mydata_sub<- na.omit(mydata$city)
but instead of getting a subset i get "values" -  "large integer 183381 elements, 1,3mb)"

Comment: Please respond to comments by *editing your original post*, instead of replying by comment

Answer (score 1):

**1.** To manipulate data in a specific column, look into `dplyr::mutate`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(A=ifelse(A==3,NA,A))
```

**2.** To remove NAs from your data, you can do:

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(A=ifelse(A==3,NA,A))
df1[complete.cases(df1),]
```

or use `dplyr::filter`:

```
df2 <- df
df2 %>% filter(!is.na(A))
```

Note that these operations remove the entire row where `A==NA`.

(It sounds like you're just trying to learn, but to get the best help, it's best to provide a small data set and a specific problem (with expected output).)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I am learning but at the same time doing a real research.
For now i took a step back and used a free dataset "LungCapData.csv" which you can find here;
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxQfpNgXuWoIWUdZV1ZTc2ZscnM/edit

I edited your command a bit for number 1.
mydata %>% mutate(Age=ifelse(Age==15,NA,Age))
And yes it did change those with age of 15 to N.A. on the printed outcome in R.
But when i refresh and re-open my dataset the 15 is still there. How come? Ps. something is off with my reply format.

Comment: ps only can change it to NA not a random number or word?

Comment: pps with mydata[complete.cases(mydata),] it deletes all NA's from my dataset, I dont want that. I only want the NA's from the column of Age.

I suppose this mydata %>% filter(!is.na(Age)) would work. However I can't test it since it doesn't change 15 into NA in my dataset

Comment: Try `mydata <- mydata %>% mutate(Age=ifelse(Age==15,NA,Age))`

Comment: Yeah that worked! And the command for question 2 as well. You really helped me well but I've got one tiny little thing left. So in summary I can now label a NA in any kind of column, I can also delete them in a specific column without deleting the other NA's. And i can also wipe the entire sheet clean of NA'S. Thanks for that. But one more thing; For now I can replace everything into a NA.. Is there also an option i can edit for example the number 72 in height to a string of text like "hello" or into a number for example "999"

Comment: I can help you but you're better off trying to learn how to use `mutate`, and the `ifelse`. Google is your friend...

Comment: That might be but R simply does not let me change it into that. Your function only works with NA. Can you put me in the right direction at least?

Comment: I'm pointing you in the right direction: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0 https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/ifelse